# Help with a logic proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

> Let $I(x)$, $x < y$, and $x ≤ y$ be predicates on naturals, where we know that $(x < y) \iff [(x < y) ∨ (x = y)]$. Given the two premises:
>
> $$∀x : ∀y : [I(x) ∧ ¬I(y)] → (x < y)$$
>
> and
>
> $$∃z : ¬I(z)$$
>
> Use the proof rules to prove the statement
>
> $$∀x : ∃y : (x ≤ y) ∧ ¬I(y)$$

I've been going at this proof for well over 3 hours now to no avail. I've tried a direct proof, proof by contradiction, and proof by cases. I've manipulated the premises to death and yet I can't seem to make any headway. I'm still extremely new to quantifier proofs and proofs in general. So, I'm asking for something to put me in the right direction. Perhaps what I need to assume in order to move forward, or a recommended strategy. I'll take any advice you can offer, I'm desperate.

Comment: Should your first sentence say "$(x \le y) \iff \cdots$"? (as opposed to strictly less than)

Comment: Moreover, it should be a universal: $\forall x:\forall y:(x\leq y\leftrightarrow (x<y\vee x=y))$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take an arbitrary $x$. We have two cases: if $\lnot I(x)$, then pick $y = x$ and you're done. Otherwise, $I(x)$. Since we know there is a $z$ with $\lnot I(z)$ by premise 2, by premise 1 we know $x < z$, so picking $y = z$ gives the conclusion.

In general, follow the structure of the formula you want to prove. It starts with a universal quantifier; okay, so pick an arbitrary $x$. Now how can we find a specific $y$ based on this $x$ that suffices? Then you can use the two predicates you want to fulfill in order to narrow down this search.